# Can you change your mind about how a multi-target burn spell assigns damage after casting it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So, my brother and i are playing mtg for fun. I have down a 
[Nezahal, Primal Tide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNezahal%2c%20Primal%20Tide%5d), a 7/7. He plays a [Fight with Fire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFight%20with%20Fire%5d) and kicks it, distributing 7 damage to Nezahal and 3 to other creatures. In response, I play a [Moment of Triumph](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMoment%20of%20Triumph%5d), giving my Nezahal +2/+2. He then declares that he is “redistributing damage”, doing 9 damage to Nezahal and 1 elsewhere. Can he do this?

Comment: Stack Exchange: Helping brothers find new ways to gain the upper hand in an argument since 2008!

Answer (score 21):

Nope.

The Gatherer rulings for [Fight with Fire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFight%20with%20Fire%5d) have this to say (emphasis mine):

> You choose how many targets Fight with Fire has **and how the damage is divided as you put the spell onto the stack**. Each target must receive at least 1 damage if Fight with Fire is kicked.

Fight with Fire is already on the stack when you respond with Moment of Triumph, so it is too late to make any changes to the way damage is divided.

Answer (score 8):

He can't do that because the distribution of damage is done as part of casting a spell.

> 601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect. Casting a spell includes proposal of the spell (rules 601.2a–d) and determination and payment of costs (rules 601.2f–h). To cast a spell, a player follows the steps listed below, in order. [...]
>
> 601.2d If the spell requires the player to divide or distribute an effect (such as damage or counters) among one or more targets, the player announces the division. Each of these targets must receive at least one of whatever is being divided.

This is summarized in a ruling for [Fight with Fire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFight%20with%20Fire%5d).

> You choose how many targets Fight with Fire has and how the damage is divided as you put the spell onto the stack. Each target must receive at least 1 damage if Fight with Fire is kicked.